# Show Loading Before Ajax call in scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load notification with pagination

If a user scroll to a perticular height I need to load next set of notification ....

This is my html

```
                            <div id="data" >
                            </div>
```

Here is my Ajax call

```
$('.notify').scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() ;//how much has been scrolled
    var innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight() ;//inner height of the element
    var scrollHeight = 950;
    if(scrollTop + innerHeight >= (scrollHeight -50)) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        $('.notification-body').scrollTop($('.notification-body')[0].scrollHeight);
        $('#data').append(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
        },
    });
    }
```

I'd like to append a Loading .......... Before the Ajax call and remove it after it complete .....

I have tried this

```
$('.notify').scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() ;//how much has been scrolled
    var innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight() ;//inner height of the element
    var scrollHeight = 950;
    if(scrollTop + innerHeight >= (scrollHeight -50)) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend:function(){
                $('#data').append('Loading........').show().fadeIn("slow");
            },
        success: function(data){
        $('.notification-body').scrollTop($('.notification-body')[0].scrollHeight);
        $('#data').append(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
        },
    });
    }
```

How to do that But it coming multiple times

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example of this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this, by using a variable for loading state and adding it in condition for ajax sending:

```js
var loading = false;
$('.notify').scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() ;//how much has been scrolled
    var innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight() ;//inner height of the element
    var scrollHeight = 950;
    if(scrollTop + innerHeight >= (scrollHeight -50)  && !loading ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend:function(){
                loading = true;
                $('#data').append('Loading........').show().fadeIn("slow");
            },
        success: function(data){
        $('.notification-body').scrollTop($('.notification-body')[0].scrollHeight);
        $('#data').append(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
        loading = false;
        },
    });
    }
```

Comment: I did typo in condition, check it again please

Comment: THe issue is that it showing "loading .....loading.....loading .....loadingloading .....loadingloading .....loadingloading .....loading

Comment: Could you create an element for the only loader? $(".loader"). If yes. You can then show it, and hide it when you need it, and don't use `append`. It's key of resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the ajax call is getting called multiple times in one scroll you could add some kind of loading boolean. That way it wont get called again until the first call is done. Optionally, you could also use a setTimeout to make the the loading a minimum length, just so the switch between loading and not loading isn't super abrupt.

```
$('.notify').scroll(function() {
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() ;//how much has been scrolled
var innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight() ;//inner height of the element
var scrollHeight = 950;
if(scrollTop + innerHeight >= (scrollHeight -50) && !this.loading) {
  this.loading = true
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend:function(){
            $('#data').append('Loading........').show().fadeIn("slow");
        },
    success: function(data){
    $('.notification-body').scrollTop($('.notification-body')[0].scrollHeight);
    $('#data').append(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
    setTimeout(()=>{this.loading = false}, 500)
    },
});
}
```

Comment: THe issue is that it showing "loading .....loading.....loading .....loadingloading .....loadingloading .....loadingloading .....loading

Comment: it seems like append(response) should be append(data.response). Also to get rid of the "....loading" that you appended you could use $('#data').text().replace("....loading", "")